# how to set_cookie value as an integer for Python Flask?

Tags: python, flask

I'm just learning the Flask framework and while doing an exercise I got caught up with an issue, for some reason I cannot store cookie as an integer and when I convert the variable `count` to a string before storing it works. Here is my code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, session, request, make_response, redirect
import os

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = os.urandom(24)
'\xfd{H\xe5<\x95\xf9\xe3\x96.5\xd1\x01O<!\xd5\xa2\xa0\x9fR"\xa1\xa8'


@app.route('/')
def index():
    if 'counter' in request.cookies:
        count = int(request.cookies.get('counter')) + 1
        resp = make_response(render_template('index.html', c=count))
        resp.set_cookie('counter', str(count))
    else:
        resp = make_response(render_template('index.html', c=1))
        resp.set_cookie('counter', '1')

    return resp

@app.route('/addtwo', methods=['get'])
def add_two():
    if 'counter' in request.cookies:
        count = int(request.cookies.get('counter')) + 1
        resp = make_response(redirect('/'))
        resp.set_cookie('counter', str(count))
    else:
        resp = make_response(redirect('/'))
        resp.set_cookie('counter', '2')

    return resp

@app.route('/reset', methods=['get'])
def reset():
    resp = make_response(redirect('/'))
    resp.set_cookie('counter', '0')
    return resp


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: All cookies data is string.

Comment: So what's the *problem*? You've discovered that it has to be a string, just convert it back and forth as needed.

Comment: Checking `if 'counter' in request.cookies` and using `request.cookies.get` is unnecessary. If the if passes, the key is there and can be accessed directly `request.cookies['counter']`. Better yet, you can remove the if entirely and just use `int(request.cookies.get('counter', 0)) + 1` regardless of whether or not the cookie has already been set.

Comment: Got it! I thought since it is stored as a dictionary it can also take integers. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is in the comments.
To not leave the question without an answer - quoting dirn:

> Checking if 'counter' in request.cookies and using request.cookies.get
> is unnecessary. If the if passes, the key is there and can be accessed
> directly request.cookies['counter']. Better yet, you can remove the if
> entirely and just use int(request.cookies.get('counter', 0)) + 1
> regardless of whether or not the cookie has already been set